# HERE SDK offline navigation is not working

Tags: android, sdk, maps, here-api

The scenario here is I am connected to a wifi and my app is calculating the route. It should still work since this supports offline navigation. There should be a way to force the SDK to work offline even if it is online. Thanks!

Here's the logs I got.

```
Application started.
03-10 10:17:43.185 32527-5764/global.Here.Map.Service.v2 D/NetworkSSLContextFactory: NetworkSSLContextFactory created successfully
03-10 10:17:43.185 32527-5764/global.Here.Map.Service.v2 D/NetworkSSLContextFactory: generateSSlContext BEGIN
03-10 10:17:43.260 32527-5764/global.Here.Map.Service.v2 D/NetworkSSLContextFactory: The number of files 164 found in /storage/emulated/0/.here-maps/certs/
03-10 10:17:43.767 32527-5764/global.Here.Map.Service.v2 D/NetworkSSLContextFactory: The number of valid certificates 164
03-10 10:17:43.806 32527-5764/global.Here.Map.Service.v2 D/NetworkSSLContextFactory: generateSSlContext END javax.net.ssl.SSLContext@25ec2d22
03-10 10:17:43.809 32527-5764/global.Here.Map.Service.v2 D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: hostname=xxxxx; servname=(null); cache_mode=(null), netid=0; mark=0
03-10 10:17:43.809 32527-5764/global.Here.Map.Service.v2 D/libc: getaddrinfo called from pid =32527
03-10 10:17:43.809 32527-5764/global.Here.Map.Service.v2 D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: ai_addrlen=0; ai_canonname=xxxxx; ai_flags=4; ai_family=0
03-10 10:17:43.809 32527-5764/global.Here.Map.Service.v2 D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: hostname=xxxxx; servname=(null); cache_mode=(null), netid=0; mark=0
03-10 10:17:43.809 32527-5764/global.Here.Map.Service.v2 D/libc: getaddrinfo called from pid =32527
03-10 10:17:43.809 32527-5764/global.Here.Map.Service.v2 D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: ai_addrlen=0; ai_canonname=xxxxx; ai_flags=1024; ai_family=0
03-10 10:17:46.815 32527-5764/global.Here.Map.Service.v2 E/NetworkProtocol: NetworkProtocol::GetTask::run exception: java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "version.hybrid.api.here.com": Unknown error
03-10 10:17:46.815 32527-5764/global.Here.Map.Service.v2 W/System.err: java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "version.hybrid.api.here.com": Unknown error
03-10 10:17:46.817 32527-5764/global.Here.Map.Service.v2 W/System.err:     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:482)
03-10 10:17:46.817 32527-5764/global.Here.Map.Service.v2 W/System.err:     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:255)
03-10 10:17:46.817 32527-5764/global.Here.Map.Service.v2 W/System.err:     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:218)
03-10 10:17:46.817 32527-5764/global.Here.Map.Service.v2 W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.HostResolver$1.getAllByName(HostResolver.java:29)
03-10 10:17:46.817 32527-5764/global.Here.Map.Service.v2 W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:232)
03-10 10:17:46.817 32527-5764/global.Here.Map.Service.v2 W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:124)
03-10 10:17:46.817 32527-5764/global.Here.Map.Service.v2 W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:303)
03-10 10:17:46.817 32527-5764/global.Here.Map.Service.v2 W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:242)
03-10 10:17:46.817 32527-5764/global.Here.Map.Service.v2 W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:397)
03-10 10:17:46.817 32527-5764/global.Here.Map.Service.v2 W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:347)
03-10 10:17:46.817 32527-5764/global.Here.Map.Service.v2 W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:515)
03-10 10:17:46.817 32527-5764/global.Here.Map.Service.v2 W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getResponseCode(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:105)
03-10 10:17:46.818 32527-5764/global.Here.Map.Service.v2 W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:25)
03-10 10:17:46.818 32527-5764/global.Here.Map.Service.v2 W/System.err:     at com.here.hype.NetworkProtocol$GetTask.run(NetworkProtocol.java:221)
03-10 10:17:46.818 32527-5764/global.Here.Map.Service.v2 W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
03-10 10:17:46.818 32527-5764/global.Here.Map.Service.v2 W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.GaiException: android_getaddrinfo failed: GAI_ error 401 (Unknown error)
03-10 10:17:46.818 32527-5764/global.Here.Map.Service.v2 W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Posix.android_getaddrinfo(Native Method)
03-10 10:17:46.818 32527-5764/global.Here.Map.Service.v2 W/System.err:     at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.android_getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:55)
03-10 10:17:46.818 32527-5764/global.Here.Map.Service.v2 W/System.err:     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:446)
03-10 10:17:46.818 32527-5764/global.Here.Map.Service.v2 W/System.err:  ... 14 more


Calculate route executed

03-10 10:21:06.554 32455-12106/com.maps.plot D/NetworkSSLContextFactory: NetworkSSLContextFactory created successfully
03-10 10:21:06.554 32455-12106/com.maps.plot D/NetworkSSLContextFactory: generateSSlContext BEGIN
03-10 10:21:06.557 32455-32455/com.maps.plot I/System.out: Route calculation progress:3%
03-10 10:21:06.630 32455-12106/com.maps.plot D/NetworkSSLContextFactory: The number of files 164 found in /storage/emulated/0/.here-maps/certs/
03-10 10:21:06.638 32455-32455/com.maps.plot I/System.out: Route calculation progress:6%
03-10 10:21:06.707 32455-32455/com.maps.plot I/System.out: Route calculation progress:9%
03-10 10:21:06.755 32455-32455/com.maps.plot I/System.out: Route calculation progress:12%
03-10 10:21:06.806 32455-32455/com.maps.plot I/System.out: Route calculation progress:15%
03-10 10:21:06.881 32455-32455/com.maps.plot I/System.out: Route calculation progress:18%
03-10 10:21:06.954 32455-32455/com.maps.plot I/System.out: Route calculation progress:21%
03-10 10:21:06.969 32455-12106/com.maps.plot D/NetworkSSLContextFactory: The number of valid certificates 164
03-10 10:21:07.001 32455-12106/com.maps.plot D/NetworkSSLContextFactory: generateSSlContext END javax.net.ssl.SSLContext@35325c17
03-10 10:21:07.002 32455-12106/com.maps.plot D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: hostname=xxxxx; servname=(null); cache_mode=(null), netid=0; mark=0
03-10 10:21:07.002 32455-12106/com.maps.plot D/libc: getaddrinfo called from pid =32455
03-10 10:21:07.002 32455-12106/com.maps.plot D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: ai_addrlen=0; ai_canonname=xxxxx; ai_flags=4; ai_family=0
03-10 10:21:07.002 32455-12106/com.maps.plot D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: hostname=xxxxx; servname=(null); cache_mode=(null), netid=0; mark=0
03-10 10:21:07.002 32455-12106/com.maps.plot D/libc: getaddrinfo called from pid =32455
03-10 10:21:07.002 32455-12106/com.maps.plot D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: ai_addrlen=0; ai_canonname=xxxxx; ai_flags=1024; ai_family=0
03-10 10:21:07.003 32455-12106/com.maps.plot D/libc: remote DNS query failed we don't need to try local DNS query result_code =401
03-10 10:21:07.003 32455-12106/com.maps.plot D/libc: dnsproxy getaddrinfo returns 401
03-10 10:21:07.003 32455-12106/com.maps.plot D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: hostname=xxxxx; servname=(null); cache_mode=(null), netid=0; mark=0
03-10 10:21:07.003 32455-12106/com.maps.plot D/libc: getaddrinfo called from pid =32455
03-10 10:21:07.003 32455-12106/com.maps.plot D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: ai_addrlen=0; ai_canonname=xxxxx; ai_flags=4; ai_family=0
03-10 10:21:07.004 32455-12106/com.maps.plot D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: hostname=xxxxx; servname=(null); cache_mode=(null), netid=0; mark=0
03-10 10:21:07.004 32455-12106/com.maps.plot D/libc: getaddrinfo called from pid =32455
03-10 10:21:07.004 32455-12106/com.maps.plot D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: ai_addrlen=0; ai_canonname=xxxxx; ai_flags=1024; ai_family=0
03-10 10:21:07.005 32455-12106/com.maps.plot E/NetworkProtocol: NetworkProtocol::GetTask::run exception: java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "v107-61-30-8.route.hybrid.api.here.com": Unknown error
03-10 10:21:07.005 32455-12106/com.maps.plot W/System.err: java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "v107-61-30-8.route.hybrid.api.here.com": Unknown error
03-10 10:21:07.005 32455-12106/com.maps.plot W/System.err:     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:482)
03-10 10:21:07.005 32455-12106/com.maps.plot W/System.err:     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:255)
03-10 10:21:07.005 32455-12106/com.maps.plot W/System.err:     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:218)
03-10 10:21:07.005 32455-12106/com.maps.plot W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.HostResolver$1.getAllByName(HostResolver.java:29)
03-10 10:21:07.005 32455-12106/com.maps.plot W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:232)
03-10 10:21:07.006 32455-12106/com.maps.plot W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:124)
03-10 10:21:07.006 32455-12106/com.maps.plot W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:303)
03-10 10:21:07.006 32455-12106/com.maps.plot W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:242)
03-10 10:21:07.006 32455-12106/com.maps.plot W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:397)
03-10 10:21:07.006 32455-12106/com.maps.plot W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:347)
03-10 10:21:07.006 32455-12106/com.maps.plot W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:515)
03-10 10:21:07.006 32455-12106/com.maps.plot W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getResponseCode(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:105)
03-10 10:21:07.006 32455-12106/com.maps.plot W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:25)
03-10 10:21:07.006 32455-12106/com.maps.plot W/System.err:     at com.here.hype.NetworkProtocol$GetTask.run(NetworkProtocol.java:221)
03-10 10:21:07.006 32455-12106/com.maps.plot W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
03-10 10:21:07.006 32455-12106/com.maps.plot W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.GaiException: android_getaddrinfo failed: GAI_ error 401 (Unknown error)
03-10 10:21:07.006 32455-12106/com.maps.plot W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Posix.android_getaddrinfo(Native Method)
03-10 10:21:07.006 32455-12106/com.maps.plot W/System.err:     at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.android_getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:55)
03-10 10:21:07.006 32455-12106/com.maps.plot W/System.err:     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:446)
03-10 10:21:07.006 32455-12106/com.maps.plot W/System.err:  ... 14 more
03-10 10:21:07.024 32455-32455/com.maps.plot I/System.out: Route calculation progress:24%
03-10 10:21:07.101 32455-32455/com.maps.plot I/System.out: Route calculation progress:27%
03-10 10:21:07.104 32455-32455/com.maps.plot I/System.out: Route calculation failed: REQUEST_TIMEOUT
03-10 10:21:50.626 32455-32455/com.maps.plot I/System.out: Location changed 42.10214493:-87.8712617
```

Comment: Seems like your device can't connect to the routing server ? Double check that your device has connectivity ? Are you behind firewall ? Maybe also a temporary issue ? In general, the Mobile SDK Premium is doing route calculation offline, if all necessary data is available offline. So, when you download the mapdata (e.g. via MapLoader) before you start route calculation, this should work. And if you request traffic aware routing, this also needs a connection to the traffic server of course.

Comment: Thanks @Marco for the response. I already have downloaded the map of the region that I am working on. I tested to browse that area and I can see the map region. The device is connected to a proxy and it was working before. If the proxy doesn't allow the request to proceed. There should be a way that the SDK will recompute the route offline.

Answer (score 0):

I have been working for this in a week and finally got this issue fixed. So I am working under company's network and it is been very unproductive because of this.

So what I did is add a proxy server under my WiFi settings because all external network request should go through the proxy or else it will have the SSL errors.